# Add the value of an EditText to a string in the strings.xml after input without a button click

Tags: java, android, dynamic, android-edittext

I'm trying to build a simple app that provides resources for an initial dyslexia evaluation in my language, so the original string is in Bulgarian, I've changed it to a sample text here.

Here's the situation:

- I have an EditText so users can input the name or nickname of the
  child, since it will later on send (hopefully) the results on e-mail
  and I want to have a personal touch in there
- after that EditText is filled I want to take its value without a
  button click and get it to update the string for the questions in the
  test.  (example: the child's name input is "**Amy**", I want the
  questions to be "When playing **____** is easily distracted" and after
  the name input to get them to change to "When playing **Amy** is easily
  distracted".

I've looked for solutions and the closest thing I could find to what I need is written below. Nothing changes on input though.

I don't mind if answers require a change in my plans - adding a button for example. But I would really love to be able to update it dynamically somehow.

My DyslexiaTestActivity.java

```
EditText childName;
String savedName;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.dyslexia_test_layout);

    DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
    int width = dm.widthPixels;
    int height = dm.heightPixels;

    getWindow().setLayout((int) (width * .9), (int) (height * .8));
    childName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name_input);
    savedName = childName.getText().toString();
    String text = String.format(R.string.dyslexia_question_one, savedName);
}

}
```

My EditText

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/name_input"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:hint=""/>
```

The string I'm trying to get the EditText to show up:

```
<string name="dyslexia_question_one">String text  <xliff:g id="name" example="Amy">%1$s</xliff:g> more string text here</string>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**you can add a listener to listen when `EditText` loses focus.**

```
 childName.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

      public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

         String question= //....get the question;
         String sWithName = 
         question.replace("xxx",yourEditText.getText().toString())
         yourTextView.setText(sWithName);

      }

      public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

      public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}
   });
}
```

modify the String and add XXX to the place where you want to put the name.

change "XXX" to dots (....) for example.or whatever you like.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! It's seems like it's what I need, makes sense, Unfortunately it crashes when I get to type the name, the keyboard gets stuck in an open state and had to restart the phone :/ Guess it's too advanced for me yet, I must be missing something somewhere